# c++ argument evaluation order for assignment?

Tags: c++

In c++, arguments evaluation of order is not guaranteed, but is the order of left/right sub expression of assignment expression is guaranteed? For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int main()
{
    int i = 2;
    std::map<int, int> map;
    map[i++] = i--;
    return 0;
}
```

Is left expression `i++` guaranteed to be executed before right expression `i--`?

Comment: Do we really need this question _yet again_?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Well, you *do* have the dupe hammer in your hands too, you can use it :-)

Comment: @Angew: Requires being bothered to find the dupe for the 120th time this hour

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I keep a few FAQ questions in my browser's bookmark toolbar, that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You asked:

> Is left expression i++ guaranteed to be executed before right expression i--?

No, it is not.

The line

```
map[i++] = i--;
```

could end up being

```
map[2] = 3;
```

or

```
map[1] = 2;
```

depending on which side of the assignment operator gets evaluated first.

However, since the line invokes undefined behavior, it could also be, as pointed out in the comment by @juanchopanza, :

```
map[42] = -999;
```

Comment: Or it could end up being `map[42] = -999;` because it is undefined behaviour.